# Сохранение строк в массив (переменную)

Tags: c, массивы, строки

Все строки, которые я ввожу в цикле, надо сохранить в массив либо в переменную. Как это сделать?

```
int main()
{
char s[100];
char arrayl[30][100];
while (s[0] !='\n' ) {
    printf("enter string:");
    fgets(s, 100, stdin);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Массив вижу. А что значит "либо в переменную"? И на основе чего выбирается это "либо"?

Answer (score 1):

Так как вы объявили массив, содержащий 30 элементов, то вы не можете ввести в него большее число элементов. В противном случае вам следует динамически перераспределять массив.

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа, которая показывает, как ввести элементы массива. Ввод завершается, если уже все элементы массива были заполнены, либо встретился конец потока ввода, либо была введена пустая строка. Вы можете изменить условие прекращения ввода по своему усмотрению.

Переменная `n` будет хранить актуальное число введенных строк.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define M   30
#define N   100

int main(void) 
{
    char s[N];
    char array[M][N];

    size_t n = 0;

    for ( ; n < M && fgets( s, sizeof( s ), stdin ) != NULL && s[0] != '\n'; ++n )
    {
        s[ strcspn( s, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
        strcpy( array[n], s );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) puts( array[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

Если были введены строки

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

то и вывод на консоль программы будет соответствовать введенным строкам, то есть

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное разобрался

Comment: @PaulFawkes, для ввода строк произвольной длины лучше сразу использовать функцию [getline](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline)